# Auto click the button when html page loads

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a image gallery in a html page. Where I have three buttons and each button is connected with image. If I click button1 then it will display the picture associates with it. I already done that. But, I want to auto click first button when page loads.
MY Javascript and HTML codes are below.

```js
var imgs = [
  //arrays index start at 0.. 
  [],

  ["http://s9.postimg.org/849kk35kr/bg_play_pause.png"],
  ["http://s9.postimg.org/u4uiegdmj/image_1.jpg"],
  ["http://s9.postimg.org/3mbv5qewr/image_2.jpg"],
];

function showImg(imgIndex) {
  document.getElementById('img1').src = imgs[imgIndex][0];
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-offset-5">

  <button type="submit" class="round-button-circle" onclick="showImg(1)"></button>
  <button type="submit" class="round-button-circle" onclick="showImg(2)"></button>
  <button type="submit" class="round-button-circle" onclick="showImg(3)"></button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call the `showImg` function on Dom load event. If you have `script` at the bottom of `<body>` you can even call the function directly, but if you have the script in the `<head>` use Dom load event.

I've also improved the code.

Use array of image paths. not nested array

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/us1eam26/)

```js
var imgs = [
  "http://s9.postimg.org/849kk35kr/bg_play_pause.png",
  "http://s9.postimg.org/u4uiegdmj/image_1.jpg",
  "http://s9.postimg.org/3mbv5qewr/image_2.jpg"
];

function showImg(imgIndex) {
  document.getElementById('img1').src = imgs[imgIndex - 1];
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  showImg(1);
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-offset-5">

  <button type="submit" class="round-button-circle" onclick="showImg(1)">First</button>
  <button type="submit" class="round-button-circle" onclick="showImg(2)">Second</button>
  <button type="submit" class="round-button-circle" onclick="showImg(3)">Third</button>

</div>

<img id="img1" src="" />
```

**Edit**

If `addEventListener` is not supported, you can use `attachEvent`.

See [addEventListener Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility)

```
if (document.attachEvent) {
    // Use attachEvent to bind event
} else {
    // Use addEventListener
}
```

Comment: worth noting the workaround for browsers that support `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I've also added workaround at the bottom of answer

Answer (score 3):

This is eventually fairly easy to accomplish by this snippet of code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    showImg(1);
}
```

Comment: No need to wait for `load` event, that's too long if there are many external resources on page

Comment: the question was "when page loads", thus the answer was naturally `window.onload`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call `showImg(1);`?

Answer (score 0):

For javaScript you can use following

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('buttonId').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Load  call a function with following code

```
var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
 e.initMouseEvent('mousedown');
 document.getElementById('buttonId').dispatchEvent(e);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code. It will auto click the button having id as "buttonId" on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonId").click(); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: this is jQuery, NOT JavaScript

Comment: window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('buttonId').click();
}